# asp.net core 2 load and display images from local disk drive

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.0, razor-pages, asp.net-core-2.2

Is there any way to display image in an asp.net core 2 (razor) web application from local drive ?

The reason I want do to this is that I'm developing a game server which contains a game server and two websites (front end and an admin panel) and all of those will require access to the mentioned images which in this case is profile images and that's why I didn't put those images in the wwwroot folder.

Sample image address: "C:\game_data\avatars\default.png"

Comment: you cannot use it directly from local drive but yes you can program it to read this file from your local drive and use it in your project either directly or after saving in project directory.

Comment: @ZubairRana so you mean I have to copy the needed image temporary to the wwwroot image and delete it later for every request ? isn't there any way to load that image into memory and display it on the web page ?

Comment: i said you can use both options after reading file i.e. "either directly or after saving in project directory." So yes you can use the file directly without saving in wwwroot.

Comment: @ZubairRana but how can the other users can see the image since the website is pointing image address to  "C:\game_data\avatars\default.png" and this file doesn't exist in viewer's system.

Comment: then your question is not complete. You should modify the question highlighting that you want to read this file from local C drive of of each user accessing your website.

Comment: @ZubairRana No sir I do not intend to do that, I want it to read from the C drive of the server and other user's be able to view the image

Comment: @Shahriyar what is the actual question? Web sites display images. ASP.Net Core sites are no different. The images can come from any path, from databases, CDNs, AWS, other services etc. All the *web page* cares is that the image source URL returns an image.

Comment: @Shahriyar For images stored on disk the *secure* choice is to store them in a path under `wwwroot` along with other static files so you don't have to give the application account any wider permissions than necessary. You can use different paths though. All that is configures in the ASP.NET Core startup code

Comment: @Shahriyar have you configured your site to [work with static files](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/static-files?view=aspnetcore-2.2)?

Comment: @Shahriyar using file from C drive for live website is not a secure way. because it needs extra permissions to read that file.

Comment: so the preferred option is to store uploaded profile images to the wwwroot directory rather than a shared directory ? The problem with that is the core game server which is a dot net core console application has to access the website's wwwroot directory to read the images

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In most cases, the most secure (and easiest) optin is to store images under the site's root folder to avoid giving the web site's account access outside the site folder itself.

User profile images aren't *static* though. That's why they're often stored in a database or other storage.

You can map a specific request path to a custom location in [UseStaticFiles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/static-files?view=aspnetcore-2.2#serve-files-outside-of-web-root). From the documentation example :

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
{
    app.UseStaticFiles(); // For the wwwroot folder

    app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions
    {
        FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(
            Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "MyStaticFiles")),
        RequestPath = "/StaticFiles"
    });
}
```

The first call configures `wwwroot` as the root for static files. The second call overrides this for requests starting with `/StaticFiles` and points to a folder called `MyStaticFiles` under the application's folder.

You could expose all profile pictures under the `avatar` path with this code:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
{
    app.UseStaticFiles(); // For the wwwroot folder

    app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions
    {
        FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(
            "X:\game_data\avatars\"),
        RequestPath = "/avatars"
    });
}
```

A better option would be to load the location from a configuration file.

Another consideration is that simply mapping the folder to a path will allow anyone to read profile pictures if they can guess their name. This may or may not be a concern.

If it *is*, you use a controller that only returns the current user's as a FileResult, eg:

```
class AvatarsController
{
    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Get()
    {
        var userID=SomehowFindTheCurrentUserID();
        var avatarPath= Path.Combine(_avatarRoot,$"{userID}.jpeg");
        return File(avatarPath, "image/jpeg");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the complete answer

Comment: Nice answer! Do you think it would be possible to pass the image to the client in Blazor Web Assembly?

Comment: @AnthonyGriggs yes. There's nothing special to this. You could use the URL in the `src` element of an `img`, `video` or `audio` tag. If you wanted to get the bytes using code you could use eg `var bytes= await client.GetBytesAsync(thatUrl);`. Saving the bytes to disk is a different story though. If you want to display dynamically loaded bytes you need to [convert them to a data URL first](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62806659/blazor-webassembly-image-jpeg-content-to-html). It's the same for Javascript

Comment: Thanks, It did work for me amazingly as is when I am debugging in localhost (I am using WASM but it is .Net Core Hosted). But upon deployment it crashed the app with a 500 error: "HTTP Error 500.30 - ASP.NET Core app failed to start". Any suggestions for deployment?

Answer (score 0):

Add below code in startup class and instead of images, set your folder:

```
app.UseStaticFiles();
            app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions
            {
                FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(
            Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "images")),
                RequestPath = "/images"
            });
```