# Blazor Webassembly image/jpeg content to html

Tags: html, image, blazor-client-side

How to get a image/jpeg (content type) file over http call in a service and then bind it to html with Blazor Webassembly?

In my case, it is coming from the MS Graph API (me/photo).
With JavaScript before I would do a url.createObjectURL(blob) and then push that into DOM.
Trying to figure out the Blazor-Client way of doing this...

Comment: may be you can try to use convert the image into base64-formatted and then show it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to achieve this by the following:

Service:

```
//(Error checking removed for simplicity)

HttpResponseMessage responsePhoto = await _HttpClient.GetAsync(GRAPH_URL_ME_PHOTO_96);
byte[] byteArrayPhoto = await responsePhoto.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync();
ImageBase64 = Convert.ToBase64String(byteArrayPhoto);
```

Razor Page:

```
@inject Services.UserService Svc
<img src="data:image/png;base64,@Svc.ImageBase64" />
```